# Nginx forward to https at specific location

Tags: nginx, configuration

In my nginx config, I intended to reach purposes below:

> 1. forward www to non-www
> 2. forward https to http
> 3. only use https on uri with pattern 'secure'

Code below reach the goals, except that at point 3, chrome shows blank page with error 'This webpage has a redirect loop'. Anybody can tell proper config for this, and/or any better code ?

Note that I write h--p in code below, since SO just wont posted if I write http.

```
   #redirect www to non-www
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name www.mydomain.org;
       return 301 h--p://mydomain.org$request_uri;
   }

   #redirect https to http, for both www and non-www
   #but process https for uri with pattern 'secure'
   server {
       ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.cert;
       ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;

       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name www.mydomain.org mydomain.org;
       root /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain/public;
       index index.php;

       access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.org_access_log;
       error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.org_error_log;

       #if has pattern 'secure', just process
       #---problem is here, chrome result 'This webpage has a redirect loop'---
       location ~ ^/(secure) {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include        fastcgi_params;
           }
       }

       return 301 h--p://mydomain.org$request_uri;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name mydomain.org;
       root /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain/public;
       index index.php;

       access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.org_access_log;
       error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.org_error_log;

       #rewrite to https if has pattern secure
       location ~ ^/(secure) {
           #rewrite ^(.*) h--ps://$host$1 permanent;
           return 301 h--ps://mydomain.org$request_uri;
       }

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended by doing ssl redirection in application level

```
Route::filter('check.ssl', function()
{
    $segment = Request::segment(1);

    if ( ( $segment == 'secure') && ( !Request::secure() ) )
        return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
    else if ( ( $segment != 'secure') && ( Request::secure() ) )
        return Redirect::to(Request::path(), 302, array(), false);

});
```